# sending html in django http response

Tags: python, html, django, httpresponse

I'm new to webdevelopment. i'm trying to send a html string as a response and my server is hosted by ptyhtonanywhere. This is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^plot/',response),]
```

This is my views function

```
def response(request):
    html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>blah/body></html>'
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

when access the /plot/ url it says 'If this is your PythonAnywhere-hosted site, then you're almost there — you just need to create a web app to handle this domain.'
But i'm just trying to send a html response to the browser. Isn't it supposed to display the html content.
what am I missing?

Comment: My guess is that you need to deploy your app [as per docs](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoTutorial/)

Comment: Check if you are importing  response method correctly from views and if regrex in urlpaters match link in web browser.

Comment: This *clearly* is not a problem with "sending html in django http response"; the error message indicates that you haven't configured your site to run on PythonAnywhere. Please choose a relevant title for your question, and show relevant information in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to read django document.and add your app in setting.py.second you must include your app urls.py into urls.py in main directory of your project.after all this you should read this :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/

Comment: should i create a new urls.py in my app because it is not created by deafult? and i have included the views file to my urls.py in the main directory

Comment: ofcourse you should.then u must include that in main urls.py.u must include views.py in your urls.py in your app directory